Is $x\mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_{N-1},F(x))$ an injection if $\partial_{x_N}F$ never vanishes?
Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb R^N$ with $F \in C^1(U;\mathbb R)$. Consider the map $\Phi(x) = (x_1,\dots,x_{N-1},F(x))$. Suppose that $\partial_{x_N}F>0$ on $U$. Is it then true that $\Phi$ is an injection? My hunch is that the answer is no, but I had trouble constructing a counterexample. To explain my hunch, $\Phi$ is an injection if and only if $x_N\mapsto F(x_1,\dots,x_{N-1},x_N)$ is an injection for every choice of $x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}$. This is true by the inverse function theorem when $\{x_N: (x_1,\dots,x_{N-1},x_N) \in U\}$ is connected (i.e. an interval). In particular, the assertion that $\Phi$ is an injection is trivial when $U$ is open and convex.

Consider the function $F(x,y) = y^3 - 3xy$ and the connected open set $U = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: y^2 > x\}$. Then, for any $(x,y)\in U$, we have $\partial_y F(x,y) = 3y^2-3x > 0$, but for $x>0$, we have $F(x,\pm\sqrt{3x}) = 0$ (the points $(x,\pm\sqrt{3x})$ are in $U$), so the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x,F(x,y))$ is not injective.
